# Nextcloud, adding user as a admin group by occ command

Tags: admin, privileges, nextcloud, usergroups

I am trying to write a script to manage users and grant privileges to a group administrator. I saw in the occ group commands that you can create groups and manipulate users on a group.
But I have not seen any command to add a group admin.

Answer (score 2):

- create user:

  `sudo -u www-data php occ user:adduser --display-name="USER_NAME" --group="admin" USER_NAME`
- check:

  `sudo -u www-data php occ user:info USER_NAME`
- more details:

  `sudo -u www-data php occ`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In the latest version of Nextcloud as of today, the first command will have to change to something like: `php occ group:adduser admin admin`. You can also do: `php occ group:adduser --help` for help on a given command.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to indicate that you would like to add user to group and also create a group if it doesn't exists yet.

Assume the group you want to work with is called "powergroup".
Furthermore I will assume your php user is "www-data".

Add the group:

`sudo -u www-data php group:add powergroup`

Show the groups:

`sudo -u www-data php group:list`

Add an existing user to the group:

`sudo -u www-data php group:useradd powergroup user`

See [the nextcloud documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html#group-commands) for more details and examples.